# Create own model in train for multiple logit regressions

Tags: r, r-caret, glm

I want to mimic a multinomial logit model using separate logistic regressions and cross validating them via caret. In the non-CV world, I want to achieve the following:

```
# Create Data-Set
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
N      <- 1000
X1     <- rnorm(N, 175, 7)
X2     <- rnorm(N,  30, 8)
X3     <- rnorm(N,0,1)
length   <- sample(0:5,N,T)
Ycont  <- 0.5*X1 - 0.3*X2  +0.01*X3 + 10 + rnorm(N, 0, 6)
# create 3 categories
Ycateg <- ntile(Ycont,3)
df     <- data.frame(id=1:N,length,X1, X2,X3, Ycateg)


df=setDT(df)[,.SD[rep(1L,length)],by = id]
df=df[ , time := 1:.N , by=id]
df=df[,-c("length")]
df$Ycateg=ifelse(df$Ycateg==1,"type1",ifelse(df$Ycateg==2,"type2","type0"))
head(df)

# aim of the model without CV - combine logit regressions
y_1=ifelse(df$Ycateg=="type1",1,0)
y_2=ifelse(df$Ycateg=="type2",1,0)

#drop the ID column
dat_model=df[,-1]

# fit the models
fit_1=glm(formula=y_1~. ,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=dat_model,control = list(maxit = 50))
fit_2=glm(formula=y_2~. ,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=dat_model,control = list(maxit = 50))

# predict
p_1=predict(fit_1,type = "response")
p_2=predict(fit_2,type = "response")
p_0=1-p_1-p_2
head(cbind(p_0,p_1,p_2))
           p_0          p_1          p_2
1 1.000000e+00 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16
2 0.000000e+00 2.220446e-16 1.000000e+00
3 4.930381e-32 1.000000e+00 2.220446e-16
4 4.930381e-32 1.000000e+00 2.220446e-16
```

So what I need, is to build my own model in the caret-framework to replicate the model above. What I have done so far is:

```
#Extend Caret
customLogit <- list(type = "Classification", library = "stats", loop = NULL)


customLogit$parameters =data.frame(parameter = c("decay"), class = c("numeric"), label = c("decay"))
customLogit$grid = function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") { }
customLogit$fit <- function(x,y, ...) {

  y_1=ifelse(df$Ycateg=="type1",1,0)
  y_2=ifelse(df$Ycateg=="type2",1,0)

  fit_1=glm(formula=y_1~. ,family=binomial(link='logit'),control = list(maxit = 50),...)
  fit_2=glm(formula=y_2~. ,family=binomial(link='logit'),control = list(maxit = 50),...)
  out = vector("list",2)
  out[[1]]=fit_1
  out[[2]]=fit_2
  return(out)
}
customLogit$predict <- function(modelFit_all, newdata, preProc = NULL, submodels = NULL,...) {
  p_1=predict(modelFit_all[[1]],newdata=newdata,...)
  p_2=predict(modelFit_all[[2]],newdata=newdata,...)
  p_0=ifelse(p_1==0 & p_2==0,1,0)
  out=cbind(p_0,p_1,p_2)
  return(out)
}


customLogit$prob <- function(modelFit_all, newdata, preProc = NULL, submodels = NULL) {
  p_1=predict(modelFit_all[[1]],newdata=newdata,type="response",...)
  p_2=predict(modelFit_all[[2]],newdata=newdata,type="response",...)
  p_0=1- p_1-p_0
  out=cbind(p_cur,p_def,p_pre)
  return(out)
}

customLogit$sort <- NULL
customLogit$levels <- function(x) x$classes




# which type of cross validation to do
fitControl <- trainControl(method = 'cv',number=5,classProbs=TRUE,summaryFunction=defaultSummary, selectionFunction = "best", savePredictions = TRUE)
# tuning parameters
grid <- expand.grid(decay = 0 )

cv=train(as.factor(Ycateg)~.,
         data = dat_model,
         method = customLogit,
         trControl = fitControl,
         tuneGrid = grid,
)
```

Sadely, I could not bring the code to work and it throws me the error:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  argument is missing, with no default
```

I assume that the problem is the `decay` parameter, but as I understood, one cannot "tune" the logistic regression model using glm, such that I don't want to introduce any "tuning" parameters.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `ntile()` function?

Comment: @ Aurele - I'm sorry I didn't load the related package which is dplyr. ntile assign each value of a numeric vector to a quantile - in the case above, the continuous value of Ycont  is converted to a vector which only do has values between 1-3. I therefore edited the question.

Comment: Missing `customSummary`?

Comment: @ Aurele - thank you for the hint! Even if I changed it to defaultSummary - the error remains the same.